# Python filter a DBF by a range of date (between two dates)

Tags: python, dbf

I'm using the [dbf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf/0.96.8) library with python3.5.
The DBF table has a column with only dates without time and another just with time. Want to retrieve records from the last five minutes.

I'm new to this module and currently see just two approaches to get a portion of the data stored in a DBF:

First, with the sympathetic SQL like query:

```
    records = table.query("SELECT * WHERE (SA03 BETWEEN " + beforedfilter + " AND " + nowdfilter + ") AND (SA04 BETWEEN " + beforetfilter + " AND " + nowtfilter + ")")
```

This would be a familiar approach but the records returned are the first records from the file and not between the given range of time. Probably it is because the sql querying is not well supported by the module? Or just I'm mistaking something in my query? And another odd is that after a few records are printed I'll get an exception: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)`. To my knowledge there are no non-ascii characters in the table.

The other approach is using the module's default way of narrowing down records.. Got stuck with the filtering, as I could use it if I would want to find one specific date and time but for a range, I have no clues how to proceed.

```
index = table.create_index(lambda rec: rec.SA03)
records = index.search(match=(?!))
```

Comment: can you make query work without using the variables?  The last clause will never be true, will it?

Comment: @joel goldstick: Thanks for the correction on the second condition. I need the variables, but here is an example of what that string looks like when variables are inserted: SELECT * WHERE (SA03 BETWEEN 15/08/2016 AND 18/08/2016) AND (SA04 BETWEEN 15:39:25 AND 15:39:25) . Even if I get rid of the second condition I have the impression that it tries to dump the whole table. And it takes a while to process the sql like query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a filter function that only tracks matching records:

```
# lightly tested
def last_five_minutes(record, date_field, time_field):
    now = dbf.DateTime.now()
    record_date = record[date_field]
    try:
        # if time is stored as HH:MM:SS
        record_time = dbf.DateTime.strptime(record[time_field], '%H:%M:%S').time()
        moment = dbf.DateTime.combine(record_date, record_time)
        lapsed = now - moment
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        # should log exceptions, not just ignore them
        return dbf.DoNotIndex
    if lapsed <= datetime.timedelta(seconds=300):
        # return value to sort on
        return moment
    else:
        # do not include this record
        return dbf.DoNotIndex
```

and then use it:

```
index = table.create_index(
        lambda rec: last_five_minutes(rec, 'date_field', 'time_field'))
```

Comment: If I try it with `index = table.create_index(last_five_minutes('rec', 'SA03', 'SA04'))`
The exception I'll get is

    File "./log_user.py", line 176, in last_five_minutes
    record[date_field] is not None
    TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: in your if statement a closing bracket is missing and the index declaration with table.create_index(last_five_minutes) doesn't work as the last_five_minutes expects arguments.

Comment: @hTech:  Fixed the `create_index` call by using a lambda.  Make sure and use the correct `'date_field'` and `'time_field'` for your dbf.

Comment: here is what my DBF looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7Nr0LNo8A9LWRaRXBGQXdiNXM/view?usp=sharing You can check that I have SA03 field but giving index = table.create_index(lambda rec: last_five_minutes(rec, 'SA03', 'SA04')) will throw an exception: raise FieldMissingError(name)
dbf.ver_33.FieldMissingError: 'SA03:  no such field in table'

Comment: @hTech:  Ah.  Pretend your field names are lower-cased and it should work: `index = table.create_index(lambda rec: last_five_minutes(rec, 'sa03', 'sa04'))`.

Comment: Wow :). I wouldn't think of that. I accepted your answer as I see that it should work out, but now I got stuck at `AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'` for `record[date_field].date() == now.date()` so can't see the results yet.

Comment: @hTech: Sorry, I was treating your date field as a datetime field.  I removed the `.date()` and `.time()`.  My code shows using the time field directly, but dbfs only have Date and DateTime, so your "time" field is probably just a Character field and you will have to convert it a time yourself before you can use it in the `now.time() - record[time_field] ...` line.

Comment: When trying to convert it by `print(time.strptime(record[date_field], "%Y-%m-%d"))` will get the exception `TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'datetime.date'>` So it seems to be of date type or what am I missing again?

Comment: I was referring to your `time` field.

Comment: well, converting to string first solved it.. but thought it needs to be transformed because it is a string instead of dbf date type.

Comment: after finding two matches it throws this exception: `File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbf/ver_33.py", line 6645, in __init__
    vindex = bisect_right(self._values, value)
TypeError: unorderable types: Record() < Record()
` What deoes this mean?

Comment: @hTech: Revised code.  You may have to alter the line where `record_time` is set if it uses a different format in the time field.